# How to know when page is ready without using jQuery (alternative way)?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$(document).ready equivalent without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)

If you have jQuery called in your page. You can simply do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() { /** code inside **/});
```

But how to do similar thing without jQuery?

Comment: You should note that `ready()` is called as soon as the DOM is ready, which might be a while before the `onload` event fires. (As you might see in the jQuery source code, that doesn't always happen, since the `onload` is the fallback).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use the `DOMContentLoaded` event.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   // ...
});
```

Note that in older IEs you need workarounds, some use the `readystatechange` event if I recall correctly.

Comment: Assuming you don't care about supporting older browsers...

Comment: Note that `DOMContentLoaded` fires before CSSOM is loaded. So anyone using `DOMContentLoaded` in the absence of jQuery would have to manually trigger page reflow/repaint first.

Comment: `document.` at the start is not needed. `DOMContentLoaded` will also trigger on `window` (or `globalThis` in general), and `addEventListener(`…`)` implies `window.addEventListener(`…`)`.

Answer (score 15):

I think the simplest way to answer your question is to answer "How does jQuery do it?" and for that, I'd recommend looking as the source code. The most relevant part of the code is at 
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L423

Here's a snippet:

```
// Catch cases where $(document).ready() is called after the
// browser event has already occurred.
if ( document.readyState === "complete" ) {
    // Handle it asynchronously to allow scripts the opportunity to delay ready
    return setTimeout( jQuery.ready, 1 );
}

// Mozilla, Opera and webkit nightlies currently support this event
if ( document.addEventListener ) {
    // Use the handy event callback
    document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", DOMContentLoaded, false );

    // A fallback to window.onload, that will always work
    window.addEventListener( "load", jQuery.ready, false );

// If IE event model is used
} else if ( document.attachEvent ) {
    // ensure firing before onload,
    // maybe late but safe also for iframes
    document.attachEvent( "onreadystatechange", DOMContentLoaded );

    // A fallback to window.onload, that will always work
    window.attachEvent( "onload", jQuery.ready );

    // If IE and not a frame
    // continually check to see if the document is ready
    var toplevel = false;

    try {
        toplevel = window.frameElement == null;
    } catch(e) {}

    if ( document.documentElement.doScroll && toplevel ) {
        doScrollCheck();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function(){
 // do something
}
```

Comment: That isn't the same as DOM ready.

Answer (score -4):

Use below script:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function funtionToBeCalled(){
// code that will be exected after dom ready
}

window.onload=funtionToBeCalled;
</script>
```

Or there is one more way.  Add onload event in body tag as below:

```
<body onload='functionToBeCalled();'>
</body>
```